# Show that if $A$ is nonsingular and has row sum 1, then $A^{-1}$ has row sum 1.

Tags: linear-algebra

Here's my proof.

Let $A=[a_{ij}] \in M_n (F)$. Now, $A = AI_n$.

Since $I_n = \begin{bmatrix} e_1 & e_2 & \cdots & e_n \end{bmatrix}$ thus, $A=AI_n = \begin{bmatrix} Ae_1 & Ae_2 & \cdots & Ae_n \end{bmatrix}$.

Consider $B = \sum_{j=1}^{n} Ae_j = A \sum_{j=1}^{n} e_j = Ax$ where $x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T$.

Observe that $B$ is a matrix whose entries are the sum of the rows of $A$, and since the row sum of every row of $A$ is 1, then, every entry of $B$ is 1. If $B = [b_{ij}] \in M_n (F)$ then $b_{ij} = 1, \forall i$.

Now, $A$ is non-singular, hence $x = A^{-1}B$ is well-defined.

Let $x = [x_{ij}] \in M_{n,1}(F)$ and let us likewise define $A^{-1} = [c_{ij}] \in M_n(F)$. Since $x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T$, then $x_{ij} = 1, \forall i$.

Thus, $x = A^{-1}B = [x_{ij}]$ where $x_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} c_{ik}b_{kj}$.

Because $b_{ij} = 1, \forall i = 1, 2, \cdots, n$, $x_{ij} = 1 = \sum_{k=1}^{n} c_{ik}$, then indeed $A^{-1}$ has row sum 1. $\blacksquare$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer is correct but rather lenghty. Here is a shorter version. It is given that $Ae=e$ (where $e$ is the vector where all elements are 1). Multiplying both sides with $A^{-1}$ yields $e = A^{-1}e$

Comment: Thanks. I realized it is much longer than your proof, but yeah, they are the same proof. Thanks @LinAlg.

Comment: Loosely speaking, if $Av=\lambda v$, then $f(A)v = f(\lambda)v$. Here $f(x) = {1 \over x}$, and $f(1) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea: putting $\;A=(a_{ij})\,,\,\,A^{-1}=(b_{ij})\;$, we have that

$$I=AA^{-1}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^na_{ik}b_{kj}\right)\implies$$

the row sum of the above product is

$$1=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^na_{ik}b_{kj}=\sum_{j=1}^n\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}\right)b_{kj}=\sum_{j=1}^n1\cdot b_{kj}=\sum_{j=1}^n b_{kj}\;\;\;\;\square$$